# Is the Quotient Group Cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

I'm just wondering how to show that a quotient group $H = (G/N)$ is cyclic?

Let $G= \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ 
Let $N = \left<(2,3)\right>$ , where N is a cyclic subgroup of G

Is it correct to say that $G$ has order $24$ and $N$ has order $2$?

Can I then say that the order the the quotient group $H$ is $24/2 = 12$?

How should I go about showing that H is cyclic?

Comment: You need to give more information on the group. Right now if $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ then the quotient is not cyclic.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE! If you have more information to give us, please, give it. That will increase the odds of your question being solved.

Comment: Please first check possible duplicates, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497328/nature-of-g-when-n-is-cyclic-normal-subgroup-of-g-and-g-n-is-cyclic) or similar ones here at this site.

Comment: @Yanko I've added more information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it correct to say that G has order 24 and N has order 2?

$G$ has order $24$ because $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ has $4$ elements and $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ has $6$ elements and $4\cdot 6 = 24$.

In order to see if $N$ has order $2$ you should check what are the elements in $N:\;$  we have the trivial element, of course, and we also have $(2,3)$. Since $(2,3)+(2,3)=(0,0),$ there are no more elements in $N,$ and so it is of order $2$.

> Can I then say that the order the the quotient group H is 24/2=12?

Yes, the order of $H=G/N$ is $\frac{|G|}{|N|}$ where $|G|=24$ is the order of $G$ and $|N|=2$ is the order of $N$.

> How should I go about showing that H is cyclic?

If $H$ is of order $12$ it necessarily takes one of the following forms

1. $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z},$ which is cyclic.  Or
2. $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

The latter is not cyclic, so you need to show that $H$ can't take that form. In order to do this, show that $(1,0)+N\in H$ is not of order $2$ but is of order $4$. (This is easy because $(2,0)\not\in N$ but $(4,0)=(0,0)\in N$.)